# how to solve android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android

my application consist of 2 autoCompletetextview(ACT), when i clicked on one of the item on the list showed. i got this error. I tried to fix it, but since yesterday, i still can't solve it. i really hope you can help me or give any suggestion solve this problem.

**FindMEPlace.java**

```
public class FindMePlace extends Activity {

    public static UkmRoute selectedPath = null;
    private AutoCompleteDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    public AutoCompleteTextView fromLocation, toDestination;
    Button search;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = null;
    final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> results_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> results2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<String> results_id2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    final AutoCompleteDbAdapter dbHelper = new AutoCompleteDbAdapter(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_me_place);

        dbHelper.open();

        //link with the layout items
        fromLocation = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
        toDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.destinationTxt);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        //---------------------LOCATION--------------------------------------
        // Reading location
        Log.d("Reading", "Reading all location..");
        List<Location> location = dbHelper.getAllLocation();
        for (Location k : location) {
            results.add(k.getLocationUkm());
            results_id.add(k.getID());
        }
        arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMePlace.this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, results);
        fromLocation.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

        fromLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  Log.d("test", "position:" + position);
                  Log.d("test", "actualname:" + dbHelper.getSingleLocation(arrayAdapter1.getItem(position)).getLocationUkm());

                String fromLoc = dbHelper.getSingleLocation(arrayAdapter1.getItem(position)).getID();
                String name = arrayAdapter1.getItem(position);
                fromLocation.setText(fromLoc);

            }
        });
```

the error is point here

```
Log.d("test", "actualname:" + dbHelper.getSingleLocation(arrayAdapter1.getItem(position)).getLocationUkm());
```

**AutoCompleteDbAdapter.java**

```
public void addLocation(Location location) {
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_LOCATIONID, location.getID()); // ID
            values.put(KEY_LOCATION_NAME, location.getLocationUkm()); //    from

            // Inserting Row
            mDb.insert(DATABASE_NAME, null, values);
            mDb.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
        // Getting single Poi
            public Location getSingleLocation(String id_location) {
                mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = mDb.query(TABLE_LOCATION, 
                        new String[] {KEY_LOCATIONID, KEY_LOCATION_NAME}, 
                        KEY_LOCATIONID + "=?", 
                        new String[] {String.valueOf( id_location)}, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                Location location = new Location(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1));
                return location;
            }


            // Getting single UKMRoute by From
            public Location getLocationName(String Location_name) {
                mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = mDb.query(TABLE_LOCATION, 
                        new String[] {KEY_LOCATIONID, KEY_LOCATION_NAME}, 
                        KEY_LOCATION_NAME + "=?", 
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(Location_name) }, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                Location location = new Location(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));
                return location;
            }


            // Getting all Poi
                    public List<Location> getAllLocation() {
                        List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<Location>();
                        //Select All Query
                        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;

                        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                        //looping through all rows and adding to list
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                Location poi = new Location();
                                poi.setID(cursor.getString(0));
                                poi.setLocationUkm(cursor.getString(1));

                                locationList.add(poi);

                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }

                        //sorting list
                        Collections.sort(locationList,new Comparator<Location>() {
                            public int compare(Location poi, Location otherPoi) {
                                return poi.getID().compareTo(otherPoi.getID());
                            }
                        });

                        // return Poi list
                        mDb.close();
                        return locationList;
                    }
```

another error is point here

`Location location = new Location(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1)`);

```
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at com.example.series1.AutoCompleteDbAdapter.getSingleLocation(AutoCompleteDbAdapter.java:452)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at com.example.series1.FindMePlace$1.onItemClick(FindMePlace.java:73)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:952)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$1400(AutoCompleteTextView.java:92)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1489)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-05 11:32:58.183: E/AndroidRuntime(30311):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check in doc what returns `Cursor.moveToFirst()` and what it means ...

Comment: You check if (cursor != null) and you should do it with if(cursor.moveToFirst()).

Comment: Size start from 1, index from 0... You can't request index 0 when size is 0. Index 0 in only available when size is bigger or equal to 1.

Comment: then, what should i do? i need to change this "Location location = new Location(cursor.getString(0),
                        cursor.getString(1));" into what?

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong (aside from lack of brackets I'd additionally punish you for):

```
if (cursor != null)
   cursor.moveToFirst();
```

The fact the cursor is not `null` does **NOT** mean it holds any data to fetch. So query can be successful (and cursor not null), but at the same time there can be zero results of that query. So before you start reading the results you need to ensure that there's data to harvest. The simplest approach would be to check if `moveToFirst()` returned `true` or call `getCount()` to get the number of results. See [docs on Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

Answer (score 0):

May this help you..

I think You havent intialized mDbhelper;

Do this : 
`AutoCompleteDbAdapter mDbHelper = new AutoCompleteDbAdapter(context);`

and `if (cursor != null)` is wrong

Comment: 'if (cursor != null)' if this wrong, what is the correct one need to be use?

Comment: use if(cursor.getCount() > 0) instead of that

Comment: can i use this way?

// check whether the cursor is null or not and make sure the cursor
// is not empty
if ( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // loop until it reach the end of the cursor
        do {
            // do something here
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
}

Comment: hmm.. do one thing write the code these way.. cursor.moveToFirst(); while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){ // your code cursor.moveToNext()} cursor.close;

Answer (score -1):

I know it's very late but i say if for another people that have this problem.
Try This code:

```
public boolean isempty(String tablename)
    {

            Cursor cur2 = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "
                    + tablename , null);

            if(cur2 != null)
            {
                Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR NOT NULL");
                    if(cur2.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR MOVE TO FIRST");
                        if(cur2.getInt(0) != 0)
                        {
                            Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR HAS INDEX");
                            if(cur2.isClosed())
                            {
                                cur2.close();
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cur2.close();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR DON'T HAVE INDEX");
                            if(cur2.isClosed())
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cur2.close();
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR MOVE TO FIRST IS NULL");
                        if(cur2.isClosed())
                            return true;
                        else
                        {
                            cur2.close();
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
            }
            else 
            {
                Log.e("DATA", "CURSOR IS NULL");
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Answers that have some explanation or comments are generally more helpful than code-only answers, especially when there is a non-trivial amount of code.